# The function waveOutUnprepareHeader returns error 33 WAVERR_STILLPLAYING

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I run the following code:

```
void SoundOut()
{
    HWAVEOUT wo;
    WAVEHDR whdr;
    whdr.dwBufferLength = std::vector<SampleType>::size() * m_format.nBlockAlign;
    whdr.lpData = reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&(std::vector<SampleType>::front()));
    whdr.dwFlags = 0;
    cout << "waveOpen result " << waveOutOpen(&wo, WAVE_MAPPER, &m_format, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL) << endl;;
    cout << "waveOutPrepareHeader" << waveOutPrepareHeader(wo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) << endl;;
    cout << "waveOutWrite" << waveOutWrite(wo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) << endl;;
    cout << "waveOutUnprepareHeader" << waveOutUnprepareHeader(wo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) << endl;;
    cout << "waveOutClose" << waveOutClose(wo) << endl;;
};
```

The stdout looks like the following:

```
waveOpen result 0
waveOutPrepareHeader 0
waveOutWrite 0
waveOutUnprepareHeader 33
waveOutClose 33
```

According to SOUNDWIN.H file the code 33 means WAVERR_STILLPLAYING. But no any sound is heard and waveOutWrite returns immediatelly (writting 88000 samples to a sound card). Suggestly this immediate return implies code 33, but then why waveOutWrite reurns immediatelly and nothing is heard?
And generally, why waveOutWrite finished successfully and nothing sounds?
Where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to prepare buffers once and then unprepare them when playback is completed. The buffers can be reused in between but it is not generally a good idea to prepare/unprepare buffers along with playback.

The problem comes from the fact that when you write the data is queued for playback immediately (and remember that waveOut API is emulation/compatibility layer only), however the buffers are returned back later on a delayed callback. See [WOM_DONE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this. It is only allowed to unprepare when the buffer is no longer in use by the API.

Comment: and no any way except of callback function usage to determine that a buffer is free to be used further? If no, how to register my own callback function to receive that message?
And more, can waveOutOpen/Prepare be called once for a buffer at styart and one at end of application while waveOutWrite many times on the same buffer?

Comment: No get notified - [`waveOutOpen(..., CALLBACK_FUNCTION, ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a different notification option from there.

Comment: See, pls, my update for previus comment. There is one additional question.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to run exactly like this. Open, Prepare 1+ buffers, then keep doing Write and have the buffers returned back to you as long as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You start playing the buffer and try to release it immediately...
You should stop the sound (call waveOutStop or waveOutReset) before cleaning everything (waveOutUnprepareHeader, waveOutClose).
Anyway, if you want to hear anything, you should stop the sound later in another function (or at least insert a Sleep before stopping the sound).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by polling the sound playback and delays:

```
WAVEHDR header = { buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
/*
* wait a while for the block to play then start trying
* to unprepare the header. this will fail until the block has
* played.
*/
while (waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut,&header,sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING) 
Sleep(100);
waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
```

[Playing Audio in Windows using waveOut Interface](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3)