# Anyone who has used WaveOut API CPP please explain what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, audio, winmm, waveout

I have been struggling with this for ages and ages and I'm starting to really get fed up, 
No matter what I try or study on I simply cannot output a sound that is not choppy regardless of how I set up the memory, few blocks, more blocks, big blocks, small blocks, different loops, different call-backs, etc, nothing seems to work and I always get a choppy sound,
I'd really appreciate if someone who know what they're doing look over my code and explain where I go wrong, the littlest of detail is appreciated to the upmost degree.
Even if you can recommend someone or somewhere to contact / post please inform me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

VOID ParseError(MMRESULT Result, LPCWSTR FunctionName)
{
    if (Result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        WCHAR Text[256];
        waveOutGetErrorText(Result, Text, 256);
        #ifdef _IOSTREAM_
        std::wcout << "\'" << FunctionName << "\'" << " : " << Text << std::endl;
        #endif
        MessageBox(NULL, Text, FunctionName, MB_OK);
    }
}

typedef short TYPE;

UINT16          U_BlockCount;
UINT16          U_BlockSize;
UINT16          U_BlockCurrent;

UINT8           U_Channel;
UINT32          U_SampleRate; // Sample Rate In Hz
UINT32          U_SampleSize; // Sample Size In Bits

TYPE*           T_Memory = nullptr;
WAVEHDR*        W_Header;

WAVEFORMATEX    S_WaveFormat;
HWAVEOUT        H_Waveout;

HANDLE          H_Mutex;

double OutPutWave()
{
    double Output;
    static double Time = 0;
    Output = sin(Time * 2 * 3.153);
    Time += 0.01;
    return Output;
}

void Write(HWAVEOUT Waveout)
{
    ParseError(waveOutUnprepareHeader(Waveout, &W_Header[U_BlockCurrent], sizeof(W_Header[U_BlockCurrent])), L"waveOutUnprepareHeader");
    ParseError(waveOutPrepareHeader(Waveout, &W_Header[U_BlockCurrent], sizeof(W_Header[U_BlockCurrent])), L"waveOutPrepareHeader");
    ParseError(waveOutWrite(Waveout, &W_Header[U_BlockCurrent], sizeof(WAVEHDR)), L"waveOutWrite");
}

void CALLBACK waveOutProc(HWAVEOUT Waveout, UINT uMsg)
{
    U_BlockCurrent = (U_BlockCurrent + 1) % U_BlockCount;
    if (uMsg == WOM_DONE) Write(Waveout);
}

INT main()
{
    H_Mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    U_BlockCount    = 4;
    U_BlockSize     = 1000;
    U_BlockCurrent  = 0;

    U_SampleRate    = 44100;
    U_SampleSize    = sizeof(TYPE) * 8;
    U_Channel       = 2;

    S_WaveFormat.wFormatTag         = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    S_WaveFormat.cbSize             = 0;
    S_WaveFormat.nChannels          = U_Channel;
    S_WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec     = U_SampleRate;
    S_WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample     = U_SampleSize;
    S_WaveFormat.nBlockAlign        = S_WaveFormat.nChannels * (S_WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8);
    S_WaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec    = S_WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * S_WaveFormat.nBlockAlign;

    T_Memory = new TYPE[U_BlockCount * U_BlockSize];
    ZeroMemory(T_Memory, sizeof(TYPE) * U_BlockCount * U_BlockSize);

    W_Header = new WAVEHDR[U_BlockCount];
    ZeroMemory(W_Header, sizeof(WAVEHDR) * U_BlockCount);

    for (UINT Idx = 0; Idx < (U_BlockCount * U_BlockSize); Idx++)
    {
        T_Memory[Idx] = 440 * OutPutWave() * 10;
    }
    for (UINT Idx = 0; Idx < (U_BlockCount); Idx++)
    {
        W_Header[Idx].dwBufferLength = sizeof(TYPE) * U_BlockSize;
        W_Header[Idx].lpData = (LPSTR)T_Memory + (Idx * U_BlockSize);
    }
    
    ParseError(waveOutOpen(&H_Waveout, WAVE_MAPPER, &S_WaveFormat, (DWORD_PTR)waveOutProc, (DWORD_PTR)NULL, CALLBACK_FUNCTION), L"waveOutOpen");
    Write(H_Waveout);
    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does that happen with audio content that was loaded from somewhere (i.e. known good) as well? The wave generation looks a bit sus.

Comment: The waveOutUnprepareHeader() call is not correct.  Hard to guess how that happened, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082645/17034) helps.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Im sorry I'm afraid no matter what I try I can't seem to implement that, I run into issue after issue and I'm not even sure why,

Comment: I think I'm just going to give up one WaveOut,